# Elastic Search and Search Ranking Models

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine, ranking

I am new to Elastic Search. I would like to know if the following steps are how typically people use ES to build a search engine.

1. Use Elastic Search to get a list of qualified documents/results based on a user's input.
2. Build and use a search ranking model to sort this list.
3. Use this sorted list as the output of the search engine to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably add a few steps

1. Think about your information model.

   - What kinds of documents are you indexing?
   - What are the important fields and what field types are they?
   - What fields should be shown in the search result?
   - All this becomes part of your [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)
2. Index documents

   - Are the underlying data changing or can you index it just once?
   - How are you detecting new docuemtns/deletes/updates?
   - This will be included in your connetors, that can be set up in multiple ways, for example using the [Documents API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html)
3. A bit of trial and error to sort out your ranking model

   - Depending on your use case, the default ranking may be enough.
   - have a look at the [Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html) to try out different ranking.
4. Use the search result list to present the results to the end user

Comment: For the step 3, the search ranking model should be embedded into ES and become part of ES? If so, how to do that? If not, meaning the searching ranking model can be operated outside of ES, then how does it communicate with ES?

Comment: I would use query time scoring, to be able to quickly try out different cases. Use for example a Terms query, and try out different boosting for different fields. See [Terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html). So basically, the query will be rather complex, and that's how you pass the information to elsticsearch.

Comment: I worked on a project before for which I build custom search ranking models and handed it to engineers to incorporate it into the search engine. The search engine was build on top of ES. I want to know how a custom search ranking model interact with ES to resort the search results.